# Mozilla Fire Fox isn't accepting Jmeter proxy certificate for script recording

Tags: performance, testing, proxy, jmeter

While recording scripts in JMeter, Mozilla Fire Fox is not accepting the JMeter certificate. I've all the settings configured correctly (Fire Fox's Proxy settings and importing JMeter certificate to Fire Fox). Note that I've the latest versions of everything (JMeter, Fire Fox as well as Java 16). I have tried re-installing JMeter, Fire Fox but it still not working. I have enabled "network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost" but its still not working. The only scripts that are being recorded are of Mozilla's certificate rejection. Please Help me out as using any any extension like Blazemeter is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start clean:

1. Delete `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Open JMeter
3. Create a test plan using [Recording Template feature](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#basic-instructions) (from main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
4. Open HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"
5. Provide the domain you're recording
6. Once HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder starts JMeter should re-generate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file
7. In Firefox under "Certificate" section open **Authorities** tab, click "Import" and locate JMeter's certificate. During importing make sure to tick `Trust this CA to identify websites`. More information: [How do I install a certificate?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1059377)

   [image]
8. Just in case [clear your browsing data fully](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox), see [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) article for more details.
9. Just in case apply the following settings to the Certificates tab of Firefox:

   [image]
10. Configure Firefox to use JMeter as the proxy:

    [image]
11. That's it, you should be able to record now

If anything goes wrong make sure to check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) first, it should contain enough troubleshooting information.